# How to fix Perl Business::Hours Bad order 2 critical error?

Tags: perl, rt

We have [Request Tracker](https://bestpractical.com) 4.4.3. There we have an automated script that uses [Business::Hours](https://metacpan.org/pod/Business::Hours) distribution. Here's the essential part:

```
sub IsApplicable {
    my $self = shift;
    my $bhours = $self->BusinessHours;
    my $ticket = $self->TicketObj;
    my $due = $ticket->DueObj->Unix;
    my $bseconds = $bhours->between( time(), $due );
}
```

Sometimes we get an error to stderr:

```
[23406] [Wed Mar 13 07:40:09 2019] [critical]: Set::IntSpan::_copy_run_list: Bad order 2: 1552462809-1552462694
 at /usr/local/share/perl5/Business/Hours.pm line 269. (/opt/rt4/bin/../lib/RT.pm:408)
Set::IntSpan::_copy_run_list: Bad order 2: 1552462809-1552462694
 at /usr/local/share/perl5/Business/Hours.pm line 269.
```

It doesn't seem to make sense, 1552462809-1552462694 pretty much evaluates to 115.

How to analyze/fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation Business::Hours:

> between START, END
>
> Returns the number of business seconds between START and END Both
>   START and END should be specified in seconds since the epoch.
>
> Returns -1 if START or END are outside the calculated business hours.

So probably END must be greater than START

Comment: -1 is not an error, it's -1.

But maybe you are right concerning that END must be greater than START, but how do we know for sure?

Comment: They're numbers, so use numerical comparison operators. `my $now = time(); return ... if $now >= $due; my $bseconds = $bhours->between( $now, $due ); ...`

Comment: The quoted text doesn't really explain why it's not working. Your last sentence does. More precisely, Business::Hours uses Set::IntSpan to compute the period duration, and Set::IntSpan wants Start to be greater than End (see in the [source](https://metacpan.org/release/Set-IntSpan/source/IntSpan.pm#L329) of Set::IntSpan, which was [called](https://metacpan.org/release/Business-Hours/source/lib/Business/Hours.pm#L270) at some point by Business::Hours).

Comment: OK, thanks everyone, replaced $due and time(), because besides the error the script didn't work as needed.